# How to using pdf.js with asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf.js

how can view pdf file by pdf.js in asp.net page with c# language ?
my pdf file is stored in :

```
pdfpath = dr["FolderPath"].ToString() + "/" + dr["FilePath"].ToString() + ".pdf";
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

pdf.js runs in the browser. You'll need to create an action / handler so the pdf can be downloaded from your asp.net server.